# Cascading Picker inXamarin Forms MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, picker, cascadingdropdown

I have a question, how can I make a cascading selector to link all states in the selected city?

This code retrieves all cities and states, but one thing I can't figure out is how to take the selected city value and synchronize it with the state.

This is the ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {  
public async void GetCities()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var uri = Constants.BaseApiAddress + "api/GetCities";
                var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                var CitiesList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CityModel>>(result);
                Cities = new ObservableCollection<CityModel>(CitiesList);
            }
        }

        public async void GetStates()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var uri = Constants.BaseApiAddress + "api/GetStates";
                var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                var StatesList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StateModel>>(result);
                States = new ObservableCollection<StateModel>(StatesList);
            }
        }

StateModel _selectedState;
        public StateModel SelectedState
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedState;
            }
            set
            {
                if (SelectedState!= value)
                {
                    _selectedState = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
CityModel _selectedCity;
        public CityModel SelectedCity
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedCity;
            }
            set
            {
                if (SelectedCity != value)
                {
                    _selectedCity = value;

                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

This is the XAML

```
<Picker x:Name="CityPicker" Title="Select City"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" 
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding City}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}" />

            <Picker x:Name="StatePicker" Title="Select State"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding States}" 
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding State}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedState}" />
```

Comment: "all states in the selected city" - I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this works, unless that's a typo.  That said, whenever `SelectedState` is set, just update the `Cities` property to contain just the cities in that state.

Answer (score 0):

Simply update the `Cities` property inside of `SelectedState` setter:

```
        public StateModel SelectedState
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedState;
            }
            set
            {
                if (SelectedState!= value)
                {
                    _selectedState = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                   if (value != null)
                        //Cities =  RetrieveCitiesByState((CityModel) value); //update Cities according to the new selected State (value)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I updated the code, I would like you to take a look because I didn't understand where you got this method RetrieveCitiesByState ((CityModel)

Comment: I just put a dummy method name because your question didn't include details, I can't tell exactly how your api is working, but based on `GetCities()` it seems it returning all Cities whatever is the selected State, if this is true than you need to modify your backend api to return cities based on a parameter you send which is the State model, it should return only cities of that state.